# What does it mean, when Term::ReadKey::ReadKey returns "0"?

Tags: perl, getc, readkey

With `dumpkeys --long-info` called in a Linux-Terminal I get these values:

```
# ...
0x0000  nul
0x0001  Control_a
0x0002  Control_b
0x0003  Control_c
0x0004  Control_d
# ...
```

When I run this script and press `Ctrl a` or `Ctrl b` I get the corresponding values.
When I press `Ctrl Space` `ReadKey` returns `0`.
Does this null mean it is the value of `Ctrl Space` or does it mean there is something not set or empty?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ReadKey;

ReadMode('cbreak');
print "Press keys to see their ASCII values.  Use Ctrl-C to quit.\n";

while (1) {
    my $char = ReadKey(0);
    last unless defined $char;
    printf("$char -> Hex: %x\n", ord($char), ord($char));
}

ReadMode('normal');

# -> Hex: 1  # Ctrl a
# -> Hex: 2  # Ctrl b
# -> Hex: 4  # Ctrl d
# -> Hex: 0  # Ctrl Space
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showkey -a` shows me

```
^A        1 0001 0x01   #  Ctrl a
^B        2 0002 0x02   #  Ctrl b
^@        0 0000 0x00   #  Ctrl Space
```

and in [this](https://superuser.com/a/258834/26076) answer is said that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> sends ASCII NUL so I'm assuming 0 is for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> what 1 is for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>